# Inside of mesh is see through when trying to make a hole?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices, faces

I am trying to make a hole in this mesh:

[image]

but when I delete the vertices/faces, this happens:

[image]

How can I delete the top and bottom in the middle without this happening? I want the inside to look like how it does on the outside, not look like there is stuff missing.

What it looks like when rendered:
[image]

Comment: How does it look like when rendered, are they only missing in the viewport? Backface culling would've been my first guess, but that's not it according to you.

Comment: Just went into Rendered shading, and it looks like how it should. But if I import it into another program (like Roblox Studio) it looks like how it does with the inside missing and if the rendered shading was turned off.

Comment: So the screenshot isn't from Blender but Roblox Studio?

Comment: No, the screenshot is from Blender, I just mean that when I save the model like that, it shows it the same in that program as it does in Blender.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? Anyway the behavior would make sense when at some point backface culling would be involved, because that discards faces with normals pointing away. Essentially you don't have faces with normals pointing inside. The proper way of solving this is by actually modelling the inside by extruding and offsetting the top ring and connecting it at the bottom.

Comment: Or using the Solidify modifier.

Answer (score 0):

After finishing your model do the following:

- press <kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire mesh
- press <kbd>W</kbd>, select remove doubles
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to correctly orient the normal ones
- press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything
- exit to object mode and export following the instructions

### NOTE:

your blender is probably damaged, or some addon is causing you conflicts

I made the following example I exported it to unity, roblox and U4, and it worked well, it is possible to say that the risk of having a bad problem or having problems is greater because I use my own compilation and fork of blender to work, which I have modified in many parts, if you use a release version of blender.org you shouldn't have any major problems than the ones I could have

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks normal to me.  The cylinder with which you started is not solid - it is hollow.  So when you round off the edge and then delete the end of the cylinder, you would expect to be left with that rounded edge only.  Blender doesn't automatically make hollow objects solid.

I presume you're making something like a mug.

Instead of deleting that end face, pull it down inside the mug to form the inside and bottom.
Alternatively, after deleting that face, select the edge of the remaining cylinder and Extrude it down inside.

Try following Blender Guru's "donut" tutorial in which he does exactly what I describe when creating a coffee cup.  You can find it here...

https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/blender-beginner-tutorial-series